# KeyDown event is not firing, KeyPreview set to true

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, keydown, key-events

I'm building a small Forms application, i've just started it.
But i have this problem:
if i put a Control to the form, the KeyDown event is not firing. I'm aware of the KeyPreview
property, and set it to true. But that didn't helped... :( I also tried to set the
focus to the main form, no success either.

Any thoughts?

Edit:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
        this.KeyPreview = true;
    }

    void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left: MessageBox.Show("Left");
                break;
            case Keys.Right: MessageBox.Show("Right");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Forms can't have the focus, *controls* must have the focus. When you try to set focus to the form, Windows will set focus to the first control on the form that accepts user input.

Comment: For what it's worth, `KeyPreview` seems to work much better with `KeyUp`, and properly handles modifier keys SHIFT, ALT, and CTRL. I've found this preferable to using `ProcessCmdKey` because shift keys are processed separately there from the key combinations, and you have to state-track them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I already commented my solution, but I also post it as an answer, so it can be easily found.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case Keys.Left:
            // left arrow key pressed
            return true;
        case Keys.Right:
            // right arrow key pressed
            return true;
        case Keys.Up:
            // up arrow key pressed
            return true;
        case Keys.Down:
            // down arrow key pressed
            return true;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you were on WPF, you could easily catch the required events, because WPF uses [routed event system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) to dispatch events. In winforms, I recomment one of these two ways:

### 1. Using [`Application.AddMessageFilter Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter.aspx):

Define a Message Filter class:

```
public class KeyMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    private enum KeyMessages
    {
        WM_KEYFIRST = 0x100,
        WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100,
        WM_KEYUP = 0x101,
        WM_CHAR = 0x102,
        WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104,
        WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x0105,
        WM_SYSCHAR = 0x0106,
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hwnd);

    // We check the events agains this control to only handle
    // key event that happend inside this control.
    Control _control;

    public KeyMessageFilter()
    { }

    public KeyMessageFilter(Control c)
    {
        _control = c;
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == (int)KeyMessages.WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            if (_control != null)
            {
                IntPtr hwnd = m.HWnd;
                IntPtr handle = _control.Handle;
                while (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero && handle != hwnd)
                {
                    hwnd = GetParent(hwnd);
                }
                if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero) // Didn't found the window. We are not interested in the event.
                    return false;
            }
            Keys key = (Keys)m.WParam;
            switch (key)
            {
                case Keys.Left:
                    MessageBox.Show("Left");
                    return true;
                case Keys.Right:
                    MessageBox.Show("Right");
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

So you have a class that every message in Windows Forms passes through it. You can do whatever you want with the event. If [`PreFilterMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter.prefiltermessage.aspx) method returns true, it means that the event should not be dispatched to it's respcetive control.

(Note that the values in the `Keys` enumeration is almost idential to [virtual key codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731.aspx))

Before this works, you have to add it to the application's message filters:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // We need an instance of the filter class
    KeyMessageFilter filter;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        filter = new KeyMessageFilter(panel1);
        // add the filter
        Application.AddMessageFilter(filter);
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosed(FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosed(e);

        // remove the filter
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(filter);
    }
}
```

The filter is only active in the lifetime of the `Form1`.

Notice: This will catch events in any form! If you want it to work for only one form, pass the form to the filter class, and compare its [`Handle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx) property with `m.HWnd` in `PreFilterMessage`

### 2. Using [Windows Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589.aspx):

This is a more advanced and complicated (and low level) approach. And it requires more code. I've wrote a `HookManager` class that makes the process very simple. I'm gonna publish the class to github and write an article about it.

Comment: This worked! Now to figure out if the Mainframe has focus. As it OF COURSE doesn't set the Focused-property to true -.-

Comment: @Stig-RuneSkansgård I just added a note in the answer for this. If you couldn't figure it out, tell me to clarify it.

Comment: Thx, I don't think that will be a problem, though I'm not sure how to detect if the key is pressed "in" the mainframe-control, because all the usual ways of telling that a control are "broken" :P In short; Now I get all keypresses on the form, but have no way of singling out the ones made in the control I want :P

Comment: Found an event on the Mainframe that fixed my problem, but as this is the post that actually got me on the track to bypass the problemcauser, you get the bounty :) Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the behaviour you observe is that special keys like TAB, UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT ARROW, PAGE UP/DOWN, HOME, END, etc. are often considered "Input Keys" by common controls.

For example, ARROW keys are considered "Input Keys" by the TabControl as these keys allows you to change the selected TabPage. A similar behaviour is present with a multiline TextBox where the ARROWS keys allows you to move the text cursor.

I assume that the Rumba Mainframe control you have does the same thing for the same reasons. You can try overriding it and changing the implementation of the IsInputKey method or handling the PreviewKeyDown event and setting the IsInputKey property to true.

Please see the documentation of the [Control.IsInputKey Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isinputkey%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Control.PreviewKeyDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown.aspx) for further details

Comment: PreviewKeyDown is never triggered, btw.

Answer (score 0):

The arrow keys are one kind of special key that are automatically handled by Controls.
So if you want to make them raise the KeyDown event you could:

1) Override the isInputKey method in every control of your form

OR

2) Handle the PreviewKeyDown event and set the IsInputKey property to true

More info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx).

I know WonderCsabo solved his problem already but someone else put a bounty on it because is having the same problem and no answer was selected.
WonderCsabo please post your solution as answer as well.

Comment: 1) Sounds VERY hacky. Also, how would you go about doing this?
2) PreviewKeyDown is never triggered when Rumba Mainframe has focus. Not the mainframe's nor the form's.

Comment: Option 1 is really bad, but it was on microsoft's suggestion so I pointed it out.
On the number 2, it only fires when some control has focus. I thought he was having problem handling the KeyDown in controls he is trying to add to his forms. Note that he omitted the controls on his code snippet.