# Why am i not able to move the picture box if i have a checkbox in my form

Tags: c#, checkbox, picturebox

I've started creating a game and i ran into a problem:
I cant place check boxes because it somehow stops the "players" movement.
I'm moving my "player" using arrow keys.

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            left = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            right = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            up = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            down = true;
        }
    }
```

And to reset the controls:

```
    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            left = false;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            right = false;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            up = false;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            down = false;
        }
    }
```

So how can i place a check box and still control my "player"?

The game working without the check box:
https://i.imgur.com/oJmn2uD.gifv

Then i put the check box and not being able to move the "player":
https://i.imgur.com/53WOGjW.gifv

What are other ways to add a checkbox sort of control that i could use for settings tab that would work?

Comment: Where did you add those checkboxes?

Comment: Set [`Form.KeyPreview = true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Checkbox takes focus and prevent form from receiving keyboard events. Another option: disable checkbox, disabled controls don't receive focus.

Comment: As a side note: Making games using "winform" controls is a bad idea

Comment: I know but im really new to coding so i just want to make some sort of a consept first. @MischaBehrend

Comment: @Sinatr i have done what you wrote and it still does not work, if i have a disabled check box how will i be able to check it then?

Comment: Have you been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10267034/1997232) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that i cant use arrows keys because they act as input keys so i replaced them with WASD and it works like a charm!