# Is it possible to shift to run off Focus in C# for a Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently working on a calculator application that looks similar to what the Windows 10 standard calculator looks like. I am practically done with it but sort of ran into an issue I thought I could fix but can't seem to figure out.

I envisioned the calculator being able to have input pressed from on the screen like pressing the "1" button "+" button etc, while also having input from the keyboard. I figured out how to have it sort of work but I have to click the button so the focus shifts to that button every time.

Is there a way to bypass the focus and just look for which button is pressed? I have looked on other posts from this website but haven't found one that seems to match my needs.

Here is my code so far,

```
private void oneBtn_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.D1 || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.NumPad1)
     {
         textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "1";
     }
}
```

Would I have to set the focus to the whole page in order to achieve what I want my application to do? Is there even a way to do this? I found an question on reddit that seemed pretty similar to what I am asking and it mentions setting the "KeyPreview" property to true. I have done this here,

```
public CalculatorPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyPreview = true;
}
```

but I am still not getting the button click from other buttons to work because the focus is still on the "1" key from loading the program up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KeyDown event is not firing, KeyPreview set to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267034/keydown-event-is-not-firing-keypreview-set-to-true)

Comment: You can take the custom *unfocusable* Button class from here: [How to keep a Form always on top without stealing focus from the active Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65439642/7444103) (C++/CLI, but the same exact thing in C#) and replace your Buttons with this one.

Answer (score 0):

you should handle the key binding in the Form Key press event, something like this

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
     // NUM PAD 1
     if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.D1 || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.NumPad1)
     {
         textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "1";
     }
     // CHAR NUM PAD 2
     ...

     // CHAR NUM PAD 3
     ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, you want to make the button which you pressed in the previous "round" of calculating lose the focus the next time the calculator is opened.

You could do that just by either coding it, e.g. `Btn_example.CanFocus = false` or you could click every button you want no focus in the Designer and under `Properties` (bottom left corner) set the `CanFocus` property to false